# State not being set properly - React Native

Tags: node.js, react-native

I am very confused by what I am getting from my code. I have the following which should log out `data.points` then set `this.state.points` to `data.points` and then log out `this.state.points`, however when it logs them out they are not equal. This is the **exact** code I am using, so I am sure it is what was outputted. I am probably overlooking something, but I have spent the past hour reading over and logging out this code, and I still cannot figure it out. Here is the code that I run:

```
console.log(data.points);

if (!this.state.hasPressed) {
    this.setState({points: data.points})
    console.log('in not hasPressed if');
}

console.log(this.state.points);
```

However in the chrome remote debugger I get this:

> `["114556548393525038426"]`
>
> `in not hasPressed if`
>
> `[]`

Comment: May want to take a gander at the [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate).

Comment: TL;DR but I probably should

Comment: Ah @Val quoted the relevant section anyways.

Comment: Yes, that was helpful :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` is an asynchronous call. you have to use function callback to wait for  `setState` complete.

```
console.log(data.points);

if (!this.state.hasPressed) {
    this.setState({points: data.points}, () => {
        console.log(this.state.points);
    });
    console.log('in not hasPressed if');
}
```

refer to react-native [setState()](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#setstate) API:

> setState(updater, [callback])
>
> setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may
>   batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state
>   right after calling setState() a potential pitfall. Instead, use
>   componentDidUpdate or a setState callback (setState(updater,
>   callback)), either of which are guaranteed to fire after the update
>   has been applied. If you need to set the state based on the previous
>   state, read about the updater argument below.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! worked perfectly. I will mark as correct in 6 minutes.